# Regarding whether to add a preposition in infinitive phrase served as attributive

Tags: prepositions, infinitives, relative-clauses

The two sentences I encountered when I read grammar book are as follows:

1. I had no place to live in.
2. A good place to eat is the Sichuan restaurant around the corner.

Regarding the 1st sentence, the grammar book says the infinitive phrase **to live in** serves as attributive to modify **place**. The sentence can be changed into: **I had no place in which I can live**. And there must be a preposition **in** to form the phrase **to live in the place**.

Thus, if the rule of the grammar book is right, there should be a preposition **at** right after **eat** and the sentence will be **A good place to eat at is the Sichuan restaurant around the corner** for the 2nd one, which makes up the
phrase **A good place at which we can eat**.

So, what do I want to know now is which one is right or both of them are correct?

Comment: Both should be ok when used in everyday speech, unless you're known for eating buildings.

Comment: @as4s4hetic Thanks for your reply.  What about the 1st sentence without the preposition in, thus changed into I had no place to live. is it still correct?

Comment: It is not natural to include the "in" or the "at". See here [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+place+to+live%2Cno+place+to+live+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20place%20to%20live%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20place%20to%20live%20in%3B%2Cc0) and here [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+good+place+to+eat%2Ca+good+place+to+eat+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20place%20to%20eat%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Of course, unless you're going there to eat the place. The "at" is nearly always elided in a sentence like this and it actually sounds much better without the "at," in spite of being both semantically and grammatically inadequate.

Comment: The infinitivals function as adjuncts of place. The "in" and at" components are contributed by the locative meaning of the adjuncts and hence there is no need to repeat them.